# How to serialise a Scala case class with Avro?

Tags: scala, avro

Following up on this question: [Avro serialisation cast error in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38936361/420892)

What is the best way to serialise a Scala `case` class with Avro?

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
 def serializeSubmapRecord(record: MyRecord): Array[Byte] = {
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val encoder = EncoderFactory.get.binaryEncoder(out, null)
    val writer = new GenericDatumWriter[GenericRecord](avro_schema)
    val r = new GenericData.Record(avro_schema);
    r.put("my_number", 1);
    writer.write(r, encoder)
    encoder.flush
    out.close
    out.toByteArray
  }
```

where the Avro schema is

```
{"namespace": "",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "my_number", "type": "int"}
  ]
}
```

However I would like to have something like this:

```
case class MyRecord(my_number: Int)
val record = new MyRecord(1)

def serializeSubmapRecord(record: MyRecord): Array[Byte] = {
val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val encoder = EncoderFactory.get.binaryEncoder(out, null)
val writer = new GenericDatumWriter[MyRecord](avro_schema)
writer.write(record, encoder)
encoder.flush
out.close
out.toByteArray
```

}

The last bit of code gives the exception of the linked question. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use a scala library, [avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s). Disclaimer: It's my project.

So you can create a schema like this:

```
case class MyRecord(my_number: Int)

val schema = AvroSchema[MyRecord]

val record = new MyRecord(1)
```

Or write out to an array of bytes like in your question:

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val os = AvroOutputStream.data[MyRecord](baos)
os.write(record)
os.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, the sample originally used a case class called Pizza which I renamed to MyRecord when copying n pasting - I seem to have missed one, which I'll edit now.

Comment: we use Scala 2.11.12, which version of avro4s is compatible with this version of Scala, because i find only RC version for 2.11

Comment: when i use that RC version, i get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a `SpecificDatumWriter` instead of a generic one.

```
case class MyRecord(my_number: Int)

val record = new MyRecord(1)

def serializeSubmapRecord(record: MyRecord): Array[Byte] = {
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(out, null);

  // specific writer
  SpecificDatumWriter<MyRecord> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<MyRecord>(avro_schema);
  writer.write(record, encoder);
  encoder.flush();
  ByteBuffer serialized = ByteBuffer.allocate(out.toByteArray().length);
  serialized.put(out.toByteArray());
  return serialized.array();
}
```

Comment: Yup. And I did not even realise it. next level of Scala-Java inter-op :D . Lesson learned - Don't code when you are too tired to remember the language you are coding in.

Answer (score 0):

Try NoSchema library
It has a more general design to decouple Scala type reflection (case class) from data type conversion (Nested Map, JSON, or Avro)
Handles SerDes with customizable rule.
The reflection part can be done with either shapeless, or runtime reflection based on TypeTag

https://github.com/yongjiaw/datacrafts